# DACircularProgress Track Circle is bigger than Progress Circle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have to draw a countdown timer circle, I m using [this open source](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress/tree/master/DACircularProgress)  library. Requirement are such that circle is filled with green and disappear in x seconds. I have given back circle green color and drawing a white circle on it and green circle looks like that it is disappearing.

```
self.circularTimer.trackTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.circularTimer.progressTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.circularTimer.thicknessRatio = 5.0f;
[self startAnimation];
```

Everything is running fine but there is a small problem, circle border is visible. As back circle is little bigger than the top white circle.

http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/1415/circleav.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your DACircularProgressView.m in function **- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context** and under this line

```
CGFloat radius = MIN(rect.size.height, rect.size.width) / 2;
```

insert this line

```
CGFloat radiusTint= MIN(rect.size.height, rect.size.width) / 2.1;
```

and replace line with

```
CGPathAddArc(trackPath, NULL, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius, 3 * M_PI_2, -M_PI_2, NO);
```

this line

```
CGPathAddArc(trackPath, NULL, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radiusTint, 3 * M_PI_2, -M_PI_2, NO);
```